What is needed to compile a client using a service call?
What is needed to compile a client to use a service offered by another node? Is only the .hpp file needed and included via the include statement or is something else required?

You'll need to include:

The .hpp generated from the .srv service definition (type of the service)
The rclcpp.hpp to bring the service node features like "create_client"

And don't forget to add and link to rclcpp and the message definition in the CMakeList.
https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Writing-A-Simple-Cpp-Service-And-Client.html
